# C++ Comparison, What is the outcome?

Tags: c++

There is simple code

```
int a( int *p0 ) {
        int p;
        if( p0 ) return p0 > &p;
        return a(&p);
}

int main() {
        puts( a(0) ? "y" : "n" );
}
```

What result will be and how many times method `a` will be called?

Comment: Why don't you run it and find out?

Comment: I somehow doubt this is defined/specified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comparing pointers using `>` is unspecified if they are not part of the same array.

So there is no actual answer, although you can assume if the stack grows down `if( p0 ) return p0 > &p;` will be true, otherwise false.